# Loop and copy data between rows

Tags: mysql

I have a simple yet difficult question.
I have the follwing table structure:

<kbd>I D</kbd> <kbd>indx_1</kbd> <kbd>indx_2</kbd> <kbd>indx_3</kbd> 
<kbd>1</kbd>   <kbd>val_1</kbd>   <kbd>val_2</kbd>   <kbd>val_3</kbd>   
<kbd>1</kbd>   <kbd>val_1</kbd>   <kbd>val_2</kbd>   <kbd>val_3</kbd>   
<kbd>1</kbd>   <kbd>val_1</kbd>   <kbd>val_2</kbd>   <kbd>val_3</kbd>   
<kbd>2</kbd>   <kbd>val_4</kbd>   <kbd>val_5</kbd>   <kbd>val_6</kbd>   
<kbd>2</kbd>   <kbd>val_4</kbd>   <kbd>val_5</kbd>   <kbd>val_6</kbd>   
<kbd>2</kbd>   <kbd>val_4</kbd>   <kbd>val_5</kbd>   <kbd>val_6</kbd>

and want a result looking like this:

<kbd>I D</kbd> <kbd>indx_1</kbd> <kbd>indx_2</kbd> <kbd>indx_3</kbd> 
<kbd>1</kbd>   <kbd>val_1</kbd>   <kbd>val_2</kbd>   <kbd>val_3</kbd>   
<kbd>1</kbd>   <kbd>val_2</kbd>   <kbd>val_2</kbd>   <kbd>val_3</kbd>   
<kbd>1</kbd>   <kbd>val_3</kbd>   <kbd>val_2</kbd>   <kbd>val_3</kbd>   
<kbd>2</kbd>   <kbd>val_4</kbd>   <kbd>val_5</kbd>   <kbd>val_6</kbd>   
<kbd>2</kbd>   <kbd>val_5</kbd>   <kbd>val_5</kbd>   <kbd>val_6</kbd>   
<kbd>2</kbd>   <kbd>val_6</kbd>   <kbd>val_5</kbd>   <kbd>val_6</kbd>

Thank you in addvance.

Comment: The val_1, val_2... areof type varchar and do not follow a certain pattern.

Comment: I have a table that deliberately contains duplicate entries. Each set of 3 rows are an identical copy. Now I want to clean the table and copy over what is in [column 2] [row i+1] to [column 1] [row i+1] and what is in [column 3] [row i+2] to [column 1] [row i+2] but leave [column 1] [row i] untouched. and that for over 2000 entries.

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, 
       concat('val_', @row := @row + 1) as idx_1, 
       idx_2, 
       idx_3
from your_table, 
     (SELECT @row := 0) r
```